# React native Push notification onRegister issue

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am getting the token but can't set it to a state nor call any function 
from onRegister method

```
 PushNotification.configure({
        onRegister: function(token) {
           alert(token.token) //works fine
       //shows an error this setState is not a function
           this.setState({token:token.token})
      //shows an error this this.sendToken.. is not a function
           this.sendTokenTOServer(token.token) 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have component structure like this,

```
  state = {}

  configurePushNotifications() {
    PushNotification.configure({ .... });
  }

  sendTokenTOServer() {}
```

Since you want to reference method of the parent class scope, you need to assign `this` as shown below and then use it, because `this` inside the onRegister method refers to the scope of the argument object passed to `PushNotification.configure()` function.

```
configurePushNotifications = () => {
   const that = this;
   PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function(token) {
        alert(token.token)

        that.setState({token:token.token})
        that.sendTokenTOServer(token.token) 

      }
   });
}
```